# Use calculated result to filter rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Please excuse my english i'm not a native.
I have an issue in Excel. I'm trying to extract rows that are satisfying certain conditions. In the table 
[image: Table and result table]
Table result must contain only rows where columns MS / MS / MRPC <> 90/90 / S09. I tried using the IF function but fail.

Can anyone help me, please, with this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: See [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). Watch the video.

Comment: It is probably a good idea if you paste your data as a table here, and not just screenshots. Also, it is a good practice to explain the code you have tried out.

Comment: can you show us the code that you used the IF function? perhaps we can check together what is wrong in your code

Comment: @Jeeped - I don't think the answer to this question is same as marked duplicate by you. That one has columns on the right provided in the table and needs a lookup. This one requires to basically shortlist just rows out of the whole database. There is no data from right side of the table to lookup the ID. (That's my interpretation atleast)

Comment: @M.L - The OP vaguely alluded to *'where columns MS / MS / MRPC <> 90/90 / S09'*. This is a two column match situation. Well, actually one column match and one column non-match but it is the same logic, just `<>` instead of `=`.

Comment: I agree this is a one column match situation (not even 2), but he is not providing these criteria to be present in columns C/D/E, like the one does, which you have marked as duplicate to. This is a database reduction problem, whereas the Qn you have marked as duplicate to, was a lookup based on 2 criteria. (So I still debate that this is duplicate)

Comment: It's not a VLOOKUP issue, as M.L. said my result is a short list where the resulted table has to meet the conditions. IF function : If(OR(C1=90;D=90;E=S09);...and this is where i got stuck. :(

Comment: Looks like @Jeeped is not convinced by our arguments. I am not sure what you can do in such cases. Best luck!

Comment: After the edit and a reread (including the clarification from the comments), this looks more like an [Advanced Filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Advanced-filter-details-BBD0CB0A-8F90-43DF-BF77-6AD3774DC420) type problem. It's still unclear on why VBA is necessary (or what VBA has already be done) and whether the results should be in place or some hypothetical location below the original data but the question has been reopened.

Comment: Jeeped, you cannot create a new table/extracting rows using advanced filter. I need a function or a vba code that is linked in the first table, the one containing all the information and based on that one, in another table my resulted rows should meet my conditions. I hope i have explained well this time.

Answer (score 0):

The way to reduce DB based on a criteria uses Array formulae and looped `INDEX`/`MATCH` functions. I have tried to recreate your table at my end in the example, as in the screenshot.

Your base data is assumed to be in `A1:E11`, and the resultant table I have is in A14 onwards. The logic is to reduce the no of Part nos based on criteria, and once we have this shortlist, we `VLOOKUP` the corresponding information.

In cell A15, use this code

A15 `=INDEX($A$2:$A$11, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$14:$A14, $A$2:$A$11)+($C$2:$C$11=90)+($D$2:$D$11=90)+($E$2:$E$11="S09"), 0), 1)`

and since this is an array formula, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter and excel will put curly brackets on its own.

Copy-paste this formula down until you see an `#N/A`, that's where the table will have no more to add.

Next step, is to `VLOOKUP` A15 in B15 by `=VLOOKUP($A15,$A$1:$E$11,COLUMN(),0)`
You can drag this formula for the rest of the table in columns up to E and down until the last valid row in the above step.

See screenshot for illustration. The whole deal is pasted as values in H:L for viewing as values.

[image]